# TypeScript not inferring props from React.ComponentType

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have the following function which I want to use to take in a `ComponentType` and its props in order to allow me to inject those props along with the `RouteComponentProps`

```js
const routeComponentFactory = <TProps extends {}>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>,
    props: TProps
) => {
    return (routeProps: RouteComponentProps) => {
        return <Component {...routeProps} {...props} />;
    };
};
```

This function works correctly if I explicitly specify `TProps`, for example:

```js
interface MyComponentProps { a: number; b: number; }
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = () => null;

routeComponentFactory<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent, {});
```

I get an error there for not providing `a` and `b` in the object.

However, if I remove the explicit `<MyComponentProps>`, the error goes away and I am allowed to call the function with an empty object.

How can I make TypeScript properly infer `MyComponentProps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable `strictFunctionTypes` you will get an error:

```
Type 'FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
```

There are two possible inference sites for `TProps` the arguments `Component` and `props` both contain the type parameter `TProps` so typescript tries to find a type that will make both sites happy. Since if `TProps` were `{}` both the argument `{}` and the props type `MyComponentProps` would be assignable to it typescript infers `TProps` to be `{}` in order to keep everyone happy.

The reason that under `strictFunctionTypes` you do get an error is that by default function type behave bivariantly (so a function `(p: MyComponentProps) => JSX.Element` is assignable to  `(p: {}) => JSX.Element`). Under `strictFunctionTypes` function types behave contravariantly so such an assignment is disallowed.

The solution to get an error even without `strictFunctionTypes` is to decrease the priority of the `props` inference site, so the compiler picks what is good for `Component` and checks it against `props`. This can be done using an intersection with `{}`:

```
const routeComponentFactory = <TProps extends {}>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>,
    props: TProps & {}
) => {
    return (routeProps: any) => {
        return <Component {...routeProps} {...props} />;
    };
};

interface MyComponentProps { a: number; b: number; }
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = () => null;


routeComponentFactory(MyComponent, {}); // Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyComponentProps'
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it allowing me to call the function with an empty object but in my case it is complaining that the MyComponent prop is invalid.

It seems the problem is it is inferring the type from the second parameter - I guess because it is matching on the simplest type.

You could define your function like this to force it to infer the correct type:

```
const routeComponentFactory = <TProps extends {}>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>
) => (
    props: TProps
) => {
    return (routeProps: RouteComponentProps) => {
        return <Component {...routeProps} {...props} />;
    };
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
routeComponentFactory(MyComponent)({});
```

And it should complain about the empty object correctly in this case.

Comment: Not a bad option, but function currying is not necesary in this case